# Joining Textfile to Shapefile Arc 10 and 10.2 Differences

Tags: arcgis-desktop, shapefile, arcgis-10.2, attribute-table, attribute-joins

I am trying to join a textfile generated in stata that includes caoname, caoid, and fips. The fips code should match to a shapefile county map that matches to the cntyidfp category.
In ArcGIS 10.0, doing a straightforward join based on these attributes works. However, in 10.2, ArcGIS only allows for the joining of the cntyidfp to the caoname, which is completely useless.
What's the difference between the two versions that makes this difficult?
I have tried exporting to an excel document first, ensuring both the fips and cntyidfp data have the same number of characters, and creating a new table of the textfile within arcgis, but none of these solutions seem to work.
What am I missing?

Comment: More information about the data and field types would be helpful.

Comment: The data includes the caoname and caoid, which have nothing to do with the shapefile and correspond to utility data. The fips number and cntyidfp correspond and are the same data, which arc 10 recognized, but are listing as one being number and one being text format. I guess that brings me to my next question of how I make them both number?

Answer (score 1):

The most likely thing without seeing the text file and knowing what field type the shapefile contains.
Is that when you add tabular data (xls, txt) to arcmap it reads the first (or first few) values in a field to determine it's type.
You can only join a type to the same type.
So fips is most likely being converted to text and when you try to join cntyidfips it is numeric.
This answer can be expanded with more information added to the question.

Comment: The fips is saying that it is in numeric format and it's type is "long". The cntyidfp from the shapefile is saying it is in "string" format. Should I convert one of them to the other?

Comment: Yes probably so